# How can I hide fields by user role when viewing a node?

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I have managed to hide certain fields for certain roles programmatically in Drupal 8 using `function module_name_form_node_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id)`.

The matter is that what I managed to hide such fields in the "Edit" tab, but I would also like to do the same in the "View" tab. What I intend to do is to hide certain fields depending on their machine name and the role of the user logged.

Do any of you know which hook should I use for that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Have you come across [Field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)? It handles both of your requirements out of the box and now has a stable release

Comment: Thanks @Clive for your answer. Yes, I have came across Field Permissions, as it's what I was initially using. Unfortunately, we are not longer allowed to use it and that's why I'm writing my own module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this code seems to be the solution:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_field_access($operation, \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account, \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) {
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'NAME_OF_THE_FIELD' && $operation == 'view') {
    return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
  else {
    return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::neutral();
  }
}
```